# .NET Regex Match Value not returning expected result

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do a replacement on a SQL query. Something like this.

```
SELECT ValueOne, ValueTwo ValueThree 
FROM DBTable 
WHERE ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}
```

The Regex pattern I am using is this

```
([A-Za-z])*\s*(=)\s*({{ReplacementValue}})
```

When I check it in a Regex validator it identifies "ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}" as the replacement value however my C# code only returns "= {{ReplacementValue}}"

Code is as follows

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z])*\s*(=)\s*({{ReplacementValue}})");
Match match = regex.Match("SELECT ValueOne, ValueTwo ValueThree FROM DBTable WHERE ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}");

if (match.Success)
{
    // Expect value to be "ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}" however it is "= {{ReplacementValue}}"
    var myValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and rewrite the question without mentioning SQL - do not expect nice  or useful recommendations for someone trying to implement SQL injection in a bit more fancy way.

Comment: You only return Group 1 value. Return the `match.Value`, and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test with much simpler regex

```js
const sql =`SELECT ValueOne, ValueTwo ValueThree 
FROM DBTable 
WHERE ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}`
 const matches = sql.match(/([A-Za-z])+[ ]?[=][ ]?({{ReplacementValue}})/gmi)
console.log(matches)
```

I know I wrote it in js but the regex should work in C# too

Answer (score 0):

Since array index in C# will be started from 0, to get entire matched value of your regex (the first group), you should get value of matched group 0.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z])*\s*(=)\s*({{ReplacementValue}})");
Match match = regex.Match("SELECT ValueOne, ValueTwo ValueThree FROM DBTable WHERE ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}");

if (match.Success)
{
    // Matched value will be "ValueTwo = {{ReplacementValue}}"
    var myValue = match.Groups[0].Value;
}
```

See demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ODqjv)